# PHP - search a similar string like the one in the array

Tags: php

I created an input text, where I write something that I want to search in an array.

I already use stristr() and stripos() but whit this I get only the same words, example:

```
<?php
    $value[0]= 'animals';
    //other array values

    $arrayResp = [];

    foreach($valuefounded as $value)
    {
          if(stristr($value, "animals") !== FALSE)
          {
            $arrayResp[]= $value;
          }
    }
```

how can I get the same result, if I type grammatical mistake like "animls"

Comment: Research "[levenshtein distance](https://www.google.com/search?q=levenshtein+distance&oq=levinstein+d&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4394j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" and the [PHP levenshtein() Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: I do not know the scope or size of the project, but Lucene, SOLR, elasticsearch are great for this.  But it's an install and learning curve so not sure if it is worth if for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but for my project, Levenshtein()  is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple function to achieve this, but you could build something like with `soundex`, `levenshtein` or similar functions. To do so, you have to split the input text into words and do the calculation for each word.

But you should keep in mind,  this works only for complete words.

```
function search_in_string($search, $text, $max = 2) {
    $words = explode(' ', $text);

    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (levenshtein($word, $search) <= $max) {
            return strpos($text, $word);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```